# Add multiple user to UNIX group in one line

Tags: bash, group

On *Centos 6.5* (and probably any) linux, I can create a group:

```
sudo groupadd mygroup
```

and add several users to it:

```
sudo usermod -a -G mygroup userA
sudo usermod -a -G mygroup userB
sudo usermod -a -G mygroup userC
```

The number of users in my particular case is `20`. How can I use a one-liner like:

```
sudo usermod -a -G mygroup userA userB userC
```

Even using for loop would be fine, but I'm not a bash specialist, so wondering.

Answer (score 20):

If `gpasswd` is available (should be on most distributions except e.g. Solaris) you can provide a comma separated list of users followed by the group name:

```
gpasswd -M userA,userB,userC mygroup
```

Comment: This one should be the answer.

Comment: Keep in mind that this solution overwrites the existing group members list. This is a different thing than "adding" users like `usermod -aG mygroup` does.

Answer (score 14):

```bsh
for user in userA userB userC; do sudo usermod -a -G mygroup "$user"; done
```

Comment: Strange that being as root this command errors out without sudo `"-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `usermod'"`

Comment: you're probably missing a 'do' or a ';'

Answer (score 2):

This is a rudimental script with positional parameters, save the code below in a file called `fill_group.sh` and make it executable with `chmod +x fill_group.sh`.

Then add it to a PATH directory (`/usr/local/bin`) or execute it in the same dir where it's located with `./fill_group.sh <group_name> <user1> ... <userN>`.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Name: fill_group.sh
# 
# Usage: 
# fill_group.sh <group_name> <user1> <user2> ... <userN>
#
# Description:
# add users to specific group passed as first parameter. 
# If the group doesn't exists add it to the system.
set -eu

# Exit if there is not at least 2 args (group,user1)
if [ $# -lt 2  ]; then exit 5; fi

group="${1}"; shift # extract group from arguments
if ! egrep --quiet "^${group}:" /etc/group; then
  sudo groupadd "${group}"
fi

for user in "${@}"; do
    sudo usermod -a -G "${group}" "${user}"
done
```

Comment: Another way to validate the group: `if ! getent group "$group" >/dev/null`

Comment: @glennjackman: thank you, i missed ``getent`` command till now (in my system there is also a nice autocomplete feature for all the _databases_ inspected).

Comment: Too complicated, I would wish to execute it from the command line.

Comment: @HordonFreeman: the script when saved is executed as a oneliner: ``fill_group.sh <group> <user1> ... <userN>``. If you want really a oneliner: ``for user in "userA userB userC"; do sudo usermod -a -G "groupName" "${user}"; done`` or if you have a the user list one per line in a file called ``users.list``: ``group=mygroup && while read user; do sudo usermod -a -G "${group}" "${user}"; done < users.list``

Answer (score 1):

On Fedora, Red Hat, CentOS and other downstream distributions, the `newusers` utility enables you to very easily add a batch of new users to a system without having to write s Bash script.

May also be available on Debian and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Tombart's and Masterfool's answers.
For old distos (SLES 11 SP1), the shadow tools are slightly different. The manuals give no version number, but are dated 2009-2010.

The -M option in gpasswd doesn't exist, (but needed gpasswd for something else). So need to go for the loop option by Masterfool. But here -a does not exist, instead -A behaves as -a & -G.

I'm doing this to rollout access to load's of systems and my complete "create group and populate" so far looks like:

```
/usr/sbin/groupadd -g GID### mygroup
gpasswd -r mygroup
for user in userA userB userC; do sudo usermod -A mygroup "$user"; done
```

So, create group with set GID, unpassword/activate the new group, add some users.