# How to allow few specified users only to edit a file?

Tags: permissions, chmod, suse

I have a file that I want only a selected group of users (approvers) to have permission to modify. The file should be read-only to the rest of the users (reviewers).

Is it possible to do this in a simple way in a SUSE linux system?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a group, add the *selected* users to that group, assign ownership, and set permissions on that file to `664`: rw for owner & group, r for everyone else.

```
$ sudo groupadd selectgroup   # create a group called "selectgroup" (or whatever you like)  
$ sudo usermod -a -G selectgroup user1 
$ sudo usermod -a -G selectgroup user2
$ sudo usermod -a -G selectgroup user3

...    # for all users to be added 

$ sudo chown someuser:selectgroup /the/file 

# where /the/file is the file to which we wish to limit rw privileges
# and someuser is presumable a member of selectgroup chosen to be the user owner

$ sudo chmod 664 /the/file
```

The above assumes that all the user members of `selectgroup` already exist on the system. If the don't you'll need to add them beforehand.

If you have a lot of users, [this script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/298900/286615) may speed things up over adding each user individually:

```bsh
$ for user in user1 user2 user3; do sudo usermod -a -G selectgroup "$user"; done
```

---

#### EDIT:

FWIW: I'm not a SUSE user, and so this may not work for you at all: Debian has a construct called **User Private Groups**, for *"Sharing and collaborating on directory content with a group"*. **UPG** is [described in their Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/UserPrivateGroups). I *think* RedHat Linux has a similar construct, and if that's an area of intersection with SUSE, perhaps it's worth a look.

Comment: You also need to take care of the directory containing the file: it must be accessible to the target group, and not writable by anyone else (anyone who can write in the directory can replace the file).

Comment: @StephenKitt: are you saying the `setgid` flag need be set (`chmod g+s /some/dir`), or that an ACL need be defined to make this work? I **think** this answer meets the OP's requirements, but please elaborate if you don't.